# AutoComplete menu Manipulation in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.2(2019)

Tags: sql, ssms

when writing a query And Autocomplete menu Appears,
is it possible to go up or down on the list without using the arrow keys? they are so far away from where my hands are.

maybe by a key near the WSAD keys?
is it customizable?

Autocomplete menu example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A keyboard remapping product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can remap any key-combination to the arrow keys.

The following example AutoHotkey script
maps `wasd` to arrow keys when CapsLock is on:

```
#If GetKeyState("Capslock","T")
w::up
s::down
a::left
d::right
```

Using AutoHotKey: Install, create a text `.ahk` file and put the above in it.
Use double-click to launch, stop it by right-click on the green "H" icon
and choose Exit. To run on login, place it in the Startup group.

Comment: Thank you, i found out that the keys in SMSS are remappable.
However, Now i have a new Problem.
i want to assign something to ALT+D however SMSS(or windows) focuses on the address bar, in spite of the fact the SMSS states that the keyboard shortcut isn't used and i can use it.
can the app you suggested help me?

Comment: AutoHotkey can do anything. You need to define exactly what you are looking for.